# how to build a suitability map in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm attaching an image of something wanting to replicate in NetLogo: a suitability analysis map. Is it possible to load various shp layers, each one representing a land attribute (use, value, slope, natural area, etc.) so they can be taken into account when occupying a patch? For example, urban occupation is more suitable where there is low land value, low slopes and near natural areas.

Thanks in advance for any help as it's going to be greatly appreciated.

Javier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMOw9.png)

Comment: have you looked at the GIS extension? You can add multiple GIS files and assign patch variables based on the GIS data. They are not 'layers' in the GIS sense, but you can access different patch variables by name to calculate suitability for different purposes. Also look at the GIS examples in the model library.

Comment: Thank you JenB. I'm new in the Netlogo environment and want to build a decision model for our local planning agency. Do you know of similar models or papers that have use shps file to assign variables to patches? I could use them as a reference as I must meet an important deadline this week. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems like QGIS or Grass GIS (or ArcMAP, but that's not free) might be better suited for what you're after (based solely on the image you provided. If you need to use Netlogo, however, check out the model library as @JenB suggested- specifically the "GIS General Examples" model. Check out the procedure in that model called "display-population-in-patches" and the `gis:apply-coverage` primitive [(dictionary entry here)](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html#gis:apply-coverage).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I must use Netlogo because the suitability analysis is part of an Agent-Based Model. I'm searching for models or papers because I want to learn how to transfer GIS values to patches but have found none yet, so your help is greatly appreciated.